# Error with plugin for vision_msgs/Detection3DArray topic visualization

Tags: ubuntu, plugins, ros, point-clouds, rviz

I'm trying to use the plugin from:

https://github.com/Kukanani/vision_msgs_visualization

But when I open Rviz y get an error message. I can add in Rviz by display type *OrkObjectDisplay* option, but I get the commented error. I am trying to see the **vision_msgs/Detection3DArray** type of topic that's why I am using this.

The error that I get in terminal is:

**[ERROR] [1697653988.707062524]: PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'vision_msgs_visualization/OrkObjectDisplay' failed to load.  Error: Could not find library corresponding to plugin vision_msgs_visualization/OrkObjectDisplay. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.**

I tried to add by display type in rviz but when I click in I get the error. Its supposed to allow visualizing vision_msgs in RViz. Message display is Detection3DArray. It should show the different types of objects in a point-cloud.